# Script highlight_focus for highlighting current screen does not work

Tags: python, window-manager, compiz

I would like to install this script from the following discussion, that allows me to highlight the current screen.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/665155/how-to-highlight-current-screen-or-window?newreg=ad5b4c91128e4c34a4c864548a7ad026

I use linux mint and the Cinnamon desktop, and I followed the instructions, installing `wmctrl`, saving the script as `highlight_focus`, logging out and executing the script with python3.

The output I receive is the following:

```
no second screen seems to be connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrizio/Documents/Linux Scripts/highlight_focus.py", line 50, in <module>
    left_scr = screendata[1][0][0]; right_scr = screendata[1][1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have three screens, two monitors (one is HDMI and the other DVI) and the original laptop screen, which is deactivated.

[image: screenshot of the "display" app]

Additionally, this is the code from the script that triggers the error:

```
def get_onscreen():
    # get the size of the desktop, the names of both screens and the x-resolution of the left screen
    resdata = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8")
    if resdata.count(" connected") == 2:
        resdata = resdata.splitlines()
        r = resdata[0].split(); span = int(r[r.index("current")+1])
        screens = [l for l in resdata if " connected" in l]
        lr = [[(l.split()[0], int([s.split("x")[0] for s in l.split() if "+0+0" in s][0])) for l in screens if "+0+0" in l][0],
               [l.split()[0] for l in screens if not "+0+0" in l][0]]
        return [span, lr]
    else:
        print("no second screen seems to be connected")
```

The script was created by [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) on Ask Ubuntu.

My system:

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18 Sarah
Release:    18
Codename:   sarah
Linux fabrizio-Lenovo-G50-70 4.6.0-040600-generic #201606100558 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:01:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output of `xrand`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, I can edit the script to work on Mint (if still needed), please mention if the current answer works for you. I think the issue is the third screen, while the original question was on two. I need to install Mint first though to be able to test. Might take a few days :)

Comment: Hello Jacob, thanks a lot for your help. I am away for a couple of days and I can not test right now, but your script is a really good idea and I am impressed. I will test as soon as I get home. Thanks a lot. Fabrizio

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! No hurry, Not going anywhere without coming back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the original script. It now checks if there are more than 1 monitor (not exactly 2). Also I changed active monitors detection logic. It still will not work for more than 2 monitors but should work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
In a side-by-side dual monitor setup (left-right), the script below will give
a short dim- flash on the newly focussed screen if the focussed screen changes
"""

import subprocess
import time

def get_wposition():
    # get the position of the currently frontmost window
    try:
        w_data = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        frontmost = subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-root", "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"]).decode("utf-8").split()[-1].strip()
        z = 10-len(frontmost); frontmost = frontmost[:2]+z*"0"+frontmost[2:]
        return [int(l.split()[2]) for l in w_data if frontmost in l][0]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def get_onscreen():
    # get the size of the desktop, the names of both screens and the x-resolution of the left screen
    resdata = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8")
    if resdata.count(" connected") >= 2:
        resdata = resdata.splitlines()
        r = resdata[0].split(); span = int(r[r.index("current")+1])
        screens = [l for l in resdata if " connected" in l]
        lr = [[(l.split()[0], int([s.split("x")[0] for s in l.split() if "+0+0" in s][0])) for l in screens if "+0+0" in l][0],
               [l.split()[0] for l in screens if not "+0+0" in l and "+0" in l][0]]
        return [span, lr]
    else:
        print("no second screen seems to be connected")

def scr_position(span, limit, pos):
    # determine if the frontmost window is on the left- or right screen
    if limit < pos < span:
        return [right_scr, left_scr]
    else:
        return [left_scr, right_scr]

def highlight(scr1):
    # highlight the "active" window, dim the other one
    subprocess.Popen([ "xrandr", "--output", scr1, "--brightness", "0.3"])
    time.sleep(0.1)
    subprocess.Popen([ "xrandr", "--output", scr1, "--brightness", "1.0"])

# determine the screen setup
screendata = get_onscreen()
left_scr = screendata[1][0][0]; right_scr = screendata[1][1]
print(left_scr, right_scr)
limit = screendata[1][0][1]; span = screendata[0]

# set initial highlight
oncurrent1 = []

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pos = get_wposition()
    # bypass possible incidental failures of the wmctrl command
    if pos != None:
        oncurrent2 = scr_position(span, limit, pos)
        # only set highlight if there is a change in active window
        if oncurrent2 != oncurrent1:
            highlight(oncurrent2[0])
        oncurrent1 = oncurrent2
```

Comment: Looks nice, will run it if I get to install Mint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is amazing. I will not be able to test it for a couple of days, but really thanks to everyone for the amazing help!

Comment: Hello, I tested It works. The problem is solved. If I ever have other problems I will make another question. I accept the answer as the solution to the problem. Thanks a lot